# Reload Chrome Extension after inline install

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have a chrome extension that we use for screen sharing.

If the user does not have the extension we prompt them to install it using the inline method. Once complete there is a call back confirming the install was successful.

At this point we run our code to capture the screen - however the extension is not yet available at this point. Once the page is refreshed, the extension seems to be available.

Is there some way to force the extension to load into the current page without refreshing. A refresh would really ruin the users experience, in this case. I have seen another application that performs this exact function as we want to.

Comment: maybe Look at injecting the code into active tab instead of relying on content script

Comment: did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @dylanjha no, sorry.

Comment: @PaulHaggo thanks for the reply!